# Accessing keywords from xml content string

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring

I have an URL which contains some texts :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"><dict><key>title</key><string>HELLO </string><key>image</key><string>http://appersian.org/upcenter/images/main3-1409057358.jpg</string><key>description</key><string>YOOHOOO</string></dict></plist>
```

I need to access keywords like `<key>title</key>` and showing them into another strings ,  here is my code to load URL :

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appersian.net/sondos/services?action=events&num=1"];
    NSError *error ;
    NSString *PageContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL
                                                      encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                         error:&error];
   NSLog(@"%@",PageContent);
```

EDITED :

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appersian.net/sondos/services?action=events&num=1"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data
                                                 options:XMLReaderOptionsProcessNamespaces
                                                   error:&error];


    NSString *string = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

but returns me null !

Comment: Have a look at `NSXMLParser` (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsxmlparser_class/reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XMLReader](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader) provides `NSDictionary` of `XMLString` and `XMLData` using `NSXMLParser`

**Uasage** :

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:xmlStringHere 
                                         options:XMLReaderOptionsProcessNamespaces 
                                           error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

### Solution:

Add [GTMNSString-HTML](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/GTMNSString%2BHTML.h) in your project to use method `gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML`

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appersian.net/sondos/services?action=events&num=1"];
NSError *error1;
NSString *strPageContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error1];
strPageContent = [strPageContent gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];
if ([strPageContent rangeOfString:@"<plist version=\"1.0\">"].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSRange range = [strPageContent rangeOfString:@"<plist version=\"1.0\">"];
    strPageContent = [strPageContent substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(range.location+range.length, strPageContent.length-(range.location+range.length))];
    strPageContent = [strPageContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</plist>" withString:@""];
}
NSLog(@"%@",strPageContent);

NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dictData = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:strPageContent options:XMLReaderOptionsProcessNamespaces error:&error];
NSLog(@"dict: %@",dictData);
```

**EDIT** : get data

```
if ([dictData count]>0) {
    NSDictionary *dictInner = [dictData objectForKey:@"dict"];
    //NSArray *arrkeys = [dictInner objectForKey:@"key"];
    NSArray *arrValues = [dictInner objectForKey:@"string"];

    NSString *strTitle = [[arrValues objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSString *strImage = [[arrValues objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSString *strDescription = [[arrValues objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"text"];

    NSLog(@"Title: %@ | Image: %@ | Desc: %@",strTitle,strImage,strDescription);
}
```

Comment: @Mc.Lover No the `xmlStringHere` is very descriptive it's your xml string not your URL so you need to do all the calls to get your xml before passing it to this method.

Comment: @Mc.Lover Have you read (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BBCGJEAC) which tells you not to use `dataWithContentsOfURL:` when making network requests and only to use when making local file requests?

Comment: @Mc.Lover : I have given solution to your answer

Comment: Thanks great answer ! but now how can I access to the keys ? I mean this gives me whole contents now I need to show just `<key>title</key>` I am trying to get string with :`NSString *getTitle = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];` but returns null